# React - Como mapear luego que cargue el componente?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Estoy iniciando con React y me esta bloqueando algo que no se de que forma resolverlo.

Mi idea es mostrar detalles de una película. A través de su ID puedo obtenerlos.
Pero al momento de querer mostrar las categorías a la cual esa película pertenece no me deja, ya que en un primer momento la respuesta llega como undefined y no puedo mapearlas.

Dentro de 'movie' guarda el objeto de la película, que por dentro tiene la categoría 'genres' que es otro objeto mas, por lo tanto tengo que iterarlo, pero no se como hacerlo.

```
function MovieView(){
  const { movieId } = useParams();
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMediaDetails('movie', movieId, setMovie);
  }, [movieId])

  return(
      <>  
        <HeaderGeneric title={movie.title} />
        
        <section className="movieView-container">
            <div className="backdropImage-container">
                <img className="backdropImage" src={`${URL_images}${movie.poster_path}`} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="movieDescription-container">
                <div className="movieDescription-header">
                    <h2>description</h2>
                    <span className="movieScore">{movie.vote_average}</span>
                </div>
                <p className="movieDescription-paragraph">{movie.overview}</p>
                <ol className="movieCategories">
                    
                </ol>
            </div>
        </section>
    </>
);
```

}

Esto es lo que devuelve genres

```
{id: 27, name: 'Horror'} {id: 53, name: 'Thriller'}
```

El objeto de los detalles es el siguiente:

```
{
"adult": false,
"backdrop_path": "/aTovumsNlDjof7YVoU5nW2RHaYn.jpg",
"belongs_to_collection": {
    "id": 91361,
    "name": "Halloween Collection",
    "poster_path": "/cq1lf9sUi10faSvqegx8dLDEeZV.jpg",
    "backdrop_path": "/d6uWYZe7h7M3F7h4IBjO1jgIkMh.jpg"
},
"budget": 20000000,
"genres": [
    {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Horror"
    },
    {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "Thriller"
    }
],
```

}

Comment: ¿Tienes un extracto de la estructura del objeto completo?  Es para ver si usa arrays o son objetos dentro de objetos hasta llegar a **genres**.  Ponlo en la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Ahi lo pongo, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Vale, ahora si que puede ser respondida bien creo. Si fuera javascript te diria que lo recorrieras con un `movie.genres.forEach( function (registro) { // y aqui escupiria la salida de cada linea con los datos por ejemplo <li>registro.name</li>  })` pero al ser reactjs no estoy seguro de como funciona.  Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo!

Comment: Asi `{ movie.genres.map(genre => <li>{genre.name}</li>) }`

Comment: Pero me tira que no se puede hacer porque movie es undefined al principio

Comment: Es que creo que también te ha dado una respuesta de javascript en lugar de reactjs. Es otro modo de recorrerlo en javascript.  Tendrás que esperar a que algún programador de reactjs lo vea, seguro que es facil también, pero desconocemos su sintaxis real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te indiqué en los comentarios, lo puedes mapear así

```
{ movie.genres.map(genre => <li>{genre.name}</li>) }
```

Pero el problema es que no tienes ningún condicional que indique si tienes o no información de la `movie` y por eso siempre te va a sacar error porque `movie` al principio siempre es `undefined`.
Si la info de la `movie` no se ha cargado, pues no puedes mostrar información, por lo tanto, puedes agregar un condicional antes del return, así:

```
if(!movie){
  return null;
}

return (<>...)   //aqui el return que ya tienes
```

Así, solo cuando ya tengas cargada la info de `movie`, ahí si renderizas sus datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, algo asi es lo que estaba buscando, sin embargo me sigue dando undefined, pero va por ahi!

Comment: Te da undefined donde? en que linea?

Comment: Me sigue dando undefined cuando lo intento usar, por ej cuando quiero hacer el mapeo no me deja porque sigue viniendo como undefined. Estaba pensando que tal vez deberia condicionar de la misma forma el parametro que llega por la url. Ya que estoy usando el parametro para mandar a llamar a la funcion 
`getMediaDetails()` que me traiga los datos de la api

Comment: Igual estoy algo desconcertado por las respuesta que me dan los `console.log()`. Siempre que mando a llamar algun array me lo devuelve varias veces, siendo que los useEffect tienen el array de dependencia. La respuesta es algo asi:

`[]`
 `[]`
`{adult: false......}`
`{adult: false......}`